# How can I add animation on flutter for dynamic list of items?

Tags: flutter, flutter-animation

I am building an app for a game where you can track the upgrade level of armor. Each level has some materials necessary to upgrade. Ex:

```
Level 1 - 10 of Materials A
Level 2 - 5 of Materials B
Level 3 - 10 of Materials C
```

I have a page where there is a star rating widget that updates the level property of my armor, when the user changes. And by using a provider, my list of materials updates to only show the remaining ones. 
So if my armor is on level 1, it shows:

```
Level 2 - 5 Materials B
Level 3 - 10 Materials C
```

And when my armor is on level 2 it shows:

```
Level 3 - 10 Materials C
```

What I want to do is to add an animation when that material leaves the screen instead of just hiding it.

This is the setup that I have to show a list of rows containing the information

```
        Column(
            children: armor.listOfUpgradeMaterials.map((material) {
          return Container(
            child: Column(children: [
                MaterialByLevelRow(material),
              Divider(
                color: Theme.of(context).accentColor.withOpacity(0.5),
                height: 0,
              ),
            ]),
          );
        }).toList())
```

Now in my `MaterialByLevelRow` widget I have an `AnimatedContainer` with

```
 height: shouldDisplayRow ? 40 : 0,
```

Is that the best option? With that, several rows will be on the screen but with height zero, isn't that a bad practice?

What if I want to add a slide-in animation with changing the height, would that be possible?

Answer (score 0):

Try using **AnimatedList()** widget.

Refer to this blog post for more help: https://medium.com/flutter-community/updating-data-in-an-animatedlist-in-flutter-9dbfb136e515